# How is this website made ? With what language or crm?

Tags: ubuntu-website

How can you create a website like [tutorials.ubuntu.com](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com)

And more specific like this: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

That you can press "next" or "done" and you go to the next step.

Comment: It was written in [Polymer](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement Jos's comment.

You can clone the repository of these tutorial pages from https://github.com/canonical-websites/tutorials.ubuntu.com and play with them using simple `./run` command or with Docker.

From [HACKING.md](https://github.com/canonical-websites/tutorials.ubuntu.com/blob/master/HACKING.md) file:

> tutorials.ubuntu.com is built with Google's Polymer, using web components
>   . You can find information about these at the following links:
>
> - https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/
> - https://www.webcomponents.org/community/articles/why-web-components